# Coldfusion 10 scheduled task cron time for every 15 minutes but only on Tuesdays

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Trying to setup a scheduled task in CF10 (Standard) to run every 15 minutes but only on Tuesdays.  A cron created said this would do the job:

```
*/15 * * * 2
```

But that gives the error "An error occured scheduling the task.
Unexpected end of expression."  I also tried

```
15 * * * 2
```

The notes say 6 or 7 space separated fields - what am I missing?  Minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week is 5 fields.

Comment: Put the only on Tuesday logic into the cfm file you are scheduling to run every 15 minutes.

Comment: That's a pretty poor suggestion Dan. Steve should be able to not mess his code up just to work around some vagary of cron schedule strings. You're supposed to offer *good suggestions*, not just any old sh!t that springs to mind.

Comment: Does the error message really say "occured", not "occurred"?

Comment: Adam yes I c&p'd out of the admin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The representation is in the below format:-

> Seconds Minutes Hours Day-of-Month Month Day-of-Week Year (optional
>   field)

So, for a task to run every 15 minutes but only on Tuesdays, below is the CRON.

**"0 0/15 * ? * TUE"**.

You can refer to the link below for more details:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06

Comment: Anit did you see the spelling mistake in that error message? Might wanna get that ticketed-up & fixed.

Comment: I missed that, but noticed your comment :) Will take it up.

Comment: Thanks @AnitKumar - that tutorial was what I needed.

Comment: That link is broken.  The documentation can now be found here: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html.

But to summarize the differences - you can use three letter abbreviations for the days of the week or the numbers 1-7 (not 0-6 like normal - meaning that Tuesday is 3).  And if you specify days of the week, ? should be used for day of the month, rather than *.